# AspIdentiy ApplicationUserManager is Static, how to extend so it participates in my IoC framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mocking

In a new ASPNET MVC application you now get the AspIdentity goodies for free.

There's a harmless little line 'plug in your email service here'.

So I did:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    private static My.Services.IEmailService _emailservice;

    public EmailService(Insolvency.Services.IEmailService emailservice)
    {
        _emailservice = emailservice;
    }

    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        _emailservice.SendEmail(message);
       return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

and now the joy:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private My.Services.IEmailService _emailservice;

    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, My.Services.IEmailService emailservice): base(store)        
    {
        _emailservice = emailservice;
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()), _emailservice);
       ...
```

as Owin kicks in it calls the Create on ApplicationUserManager in **Startup.Auth.cs**:

```
public partial class Startup 
   {
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) 
     {
        ...
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

and as I'm using AutoFac as my IoC container, in global.asax.cs

```
builder.RegisterType<My.Services.EmailService>().As<IEmailService>();
```

if the Create method is static so I get:
`_emailService` is null

I've looked here:http://forums.asp.net/post/5293670.aspx, and [How do i create an instance of UserManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924816/how-do-i-create-an-instance-of-usermanager/22924982#22924982) and [Using Autofac to provide types exported by static factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777247/using-autofac-to-provide-types-exported-by-static-factory).
but no luck.

If I change:

```
private My.Services.IEmailService _emailservice;
```

to be public non-static I feel IoC gods shaking their heads, and I can't build 'object reference required'

Answer (score 6):

Today I was struggling with the same issue (still working on it since I'm new to Asp.Identity).
I did it this way:

1. **Startup.cs (use your own container)**

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           var authConfigurator = new AuthConfigurator();
           authConfigurator.ConfigureAuth(app);
           var unityContainer = UnityConfig<MvcUnityDependencyContainer>.UseContainer();
           //Asp identity registration
           IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
           unityContainer.RegisterInstance(dataProtectionProvider);
           unityContainer.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
           unityContainer.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
           unityContainer.RegisterType IIdentityMessageService, EmailService>();
           unityContainer.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
               UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>>(
               new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext()));
           unityContainer.RegisterType<IIdentityMessageService, EmailService>();
       }
   }
   ```
2. **ApplicationUserManager (I removed static method Create):**

   ```
   public class ApplicationUserManagerService : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
   {
       public ApplicationUserManagerService(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store, 
                                            IIdentityMessageService emailService,
                                            IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
                                            : base(store)
       {
           UserTokenProvider = new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>();
           EmailService = emailService;
           Configure(dataProtectionProvider);
       }
       private void Configure(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
       {
           // Configure validation logic for usernames
           UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(this)
           {
               AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
               RequireUniqueEmail = true
           };
           // Configure validation logic for passwords
           PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
           {
               RequiredLength = 1,
               RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
               RequireDigit = false,
               RequireLowercase = false,
               RequireUppercase = false,
           };
           // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
           // You can write your own provider and plug in here.
           RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
           {
               MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
           });
           RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
           {
               Subject = "Security Code",
               BodyFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
           });
           if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
           {
               UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Controller**

   ```
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {
       private ApplicationUserManagerService _userManagerService;
       public AccountController(ApplicationUserManagerService userManagerService)
       {
           Contract.Requires(userManagerService != null);
           _userManagerService = userManagerService;
       }
       /*....*/
   }
   ```
4. **ApplicationUser**

   ```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
   {
       public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
       {
           var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
           return userIdentity;
       }
   }

   public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
   {
       public CustomRole() { }
       public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
   }

   public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
   public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
   public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
   ```

This works for me but please feel free to suggest better solution.

Comment: thanks. I will try to convert between Unity and Autofac.

Comment: Currently compiler gives error: ... the type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EmailTokenProvider<TUser,TKey>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<int>'.  Could you provide your source for IdentityModels.cs

Comment: Today RC for AspIdentity 3 has all the DI goodness we discussed pre-baked in. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs

Comment: Where are you getting AuthConfigurator from?

Comment: @free4ride how did you set up the controller? I keep getting An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. Always happens when I try to add the DBContext

Answer (score 3):

I fought with this for a long while today, and in the end, the easiest thing to do was this.

Inside of the

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
```

method, find these lines of code.

> ```
> manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
> manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
> ```

And change it to this.

```
manager.EmailService = new EmailService(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Insolvency.Services.IEmailService>());
```

I don't like the Service Locator pattern, but all of the MVC templated code uses it and it's best not to fight the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Using Unity, I added the following to `RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)` in UnityConfig.cs:

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(New InjectionFactory(x => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()));
```

This takes the ApplicationUserManager that was *already created* for the OwinContext in `Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)`, and makes it available for injection. You can keep everything else in its default setup, including ApplicationUserManager's static `Create` method.