# How to inject User Manager to Account Controller with default Identity Model in Identity 2 using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject.web.mvc, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-controller

I use Ninject on a MVC 5 project with Identity 2.

For rest of data context and controllers using that I have no problems with dependency injection.

For Account controller that uses Identity 2 model I'm getting null UserManager when I try to login:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

What is the proper way to inject required dependencies? I did not create a custom UserManager, it's out of the box model, ApplicationUserManager is as defined in IdentityConfig.cs under App_Start.

As a side note: I'm using Conventions Extension of Ninject:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind(
           x => x.FromThisAssembly()
               .SelectAllClasses()
               .BindAllInterfaces()
           );
```

Thanks.

Comment: This [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560952/aspidentiy-applicationusermanager-is-static-how-to-extend-so-it-participates-in) may help

Comment: There is nothing wrong actually, I've just injected DbContext related to Identity and all seems to work fine. Because Identity has more choices now I was kind of lost and was looking to wrong places but I'd still like to see an expert on the subject write a small tutorial for Ninject and Identity model usage.

Comment: @Bogac did you ever figure this out?  I am stuck with the same problem.  I even offered up a bounty for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239743/how-to-inject-usermanager-signinmanager?noredirect=1#comment60186132_36239743

Comment: @Bagzli it's been a long time, and frankly I don't remember, need to check project I was using this for to give an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem working with Ninject4.0, MVC5.2.3, Identity2.0 and Owin3.0.1, here you should do for working everything properly.

1. First of all you should get **Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost** from NuGet, because if you working with Owin, you want to use NinjectMiddleware.

   ```
       public partial class StartUp
       { 
            private IKernel kernel = null;
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
               kernel = CreateKernel();
               app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);
               ConfigureAuth(app);
            }

            public IKernel CreateKernel()
            {
               var kernel = new StandardKernel();
               try
               {

                  // TODO: Put any other injection which are required.
                  RegisterServices(kernel);
                  return kernel;
               }
               catch
               {
                 kernel.Dispose();
                 throw;
               }
            }
         }
   ```
2. As you can see, we have a method for injecting all services that we want, in this case we must inject **ApplicationUserManager**, **IUserStore** and **DbContext**. So for **RegisterServices** in **Startup** class, we have :

   ```
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) 
        {

           kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>();
           kernel.Bind<IUserStore<User, long>>().To<UserStore<User, Role, long, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>>();

           kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().ToSelf();

       }
   ```

   Note: I use long insted of string as a type of all keys on Identity, but 
   using a defualt (string as key) should be the same.
3. In **StartUp.Auth.cs** file that contains partial of **StartUp** class we should change **ConfigureAuth** method to this :

   ```
        internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider
        { get; private set; }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
       //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserManager.Create)

        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(
        (option, context) => {
               var kernl = context.Get<IKernel>();

             return kernel.Get<ApplicationUserManager>();

           });

            //rest of the code 
      }
   ```

   Note: we get **ApplicationUserManager** from **owin** **before** but **now** we get it from **Ninject kernel**.please notice we create a internal static property for **DataProtectionProvider** and set it from appBuilder, we're going to use this property in **IdentityConfig/ApplicationUserManager**.(see it later)
4. Now we must change **ApplicationUserManager**, we remove code from **Create** method to **constructor** with just one dependency with **IUserStore**, here is the final look:

   ```
          public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User,long>
          {
           public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<User,long> store)
              :base(store)
             {


             this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, long>(this)
               {
                  AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                  RequireUniqueEmail = true
                };
            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            this.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
                {
                   RequiredLength = 6,
                   RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                   RequireDigit = true,
                   RequireLowercase = true,
                   RequireUppercase = true,
                };

             var dataProtectionProvider = Startup.DataProtectionProvider;

            // this is unchanged
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
               IDataProtector dataProtector = 
                     dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity");

               this.UserTokenProvider = 
                 new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User,long>(dataProtector);
            }
         }
      }
   ```
5. at last we can use **ApplicationUserManager** in our **Accountcontroller's** **constructor** like this:

   ```
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationUserManager UserManager ;
        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager){

               UserManager = userManager;
        }
       // all apis come here

     }
   ```

Comment: Accepted your answer, but didn't test it (I'm on a different platform now). If anybody rejects I will change it.

Comment: unfortunately var kernl = context.Get<IKernel>(); is not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the mentioned lines in your question from your code and replace it with the following:

```
public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
        }

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }
        public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```